# Calling a method inside an object doesn't work

Tags: jquery

The close function should show an X letter as span when you click the Contact Us button, but it doesn't show up. Can you   help me?
This is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QmqNKG

Thank you...

HTML:

```
<div id="contact">
        <form>
            <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Email"></p>
            <p><textarea name="name" placeholder="Message"></textarea></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
        </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contact{width:550px;margin:40px auto;}
.js #contact{display:none;position:absolute;top:81px;background:#ccc;width:550px;}
.js #contact form {text-align:center;}
```

JS:

```
(function(){
            $('html').addClass('js');
            var container = $('#contact');
            var contactForm = {
                init: function() {
                    $('<button></button>', {
                        text: 'Contact Us'
                    })
                    .insertAfter(container)
                    .on('click', this.show)
                },
                show: function() {
                    contactForm.close;
                    container.show();
                },
                hide: function() {
                    container.hide();
                },
                close: function() {
                    $('<span><span>', {
                        text: 'X',
                        class: 'close'
                    })
                    .prependTo(container)
                    .on('click', contactForm.hide)
                }
            };
            contactForm.init();
        }());
```

Comment: There is a reason why SO does not allow links without any code. Please don't circumvent that requirement: having actual code within the question helps to establish the context of your problem.

Comment: @Terry Sure, no problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close span tag properly in close function and call contactForm.close() function in show function.
Take a look:

```
show: function() {
    contactForm.close();
    container.show();
},
hide: function() {
    container.hide();
    // remove x span
    $('.close').remove();
},
close: function() {
    $('<span></span>', {
        text: 'x',
        class: 'close'
    })
    .prependTo(container)
    .on('click', contactForm.hide)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's fixing the problem yes, but I'm learning here, I want to know why my text/class doesn't work. In the show method it worked but not in the close method!

Comment: Yup...  Now i tried with your old code and edited hide function with: 
    container.hide();
    $('.close').remove();           it worked... wierd

Comment: finally found it... your <span> tag must close properly with </span>

Comment: I missed that error, but still that doesn't fix the problem :) You know what I'll give up on this, and we'll use your solution for now. I'll comeback to it in the future maybe. Thanks a lot my friend!

Comment: Not a problem my man, glad i could help. I found the solution, this time is guarnteed: you need to call the contactForm.close() function inside show function.